# How to write a Vec<u8> to a file?

Tags: file, rust, vector

I have a base64 image and got `Vec<u8>` from it and write them to a file.
Here is my code:

```rust
let file_contents_base64: Vec<u8> = image_base64::from_base64(
    String::from(&file_contents_string_vec[0])
);
```

I want to write the `file_contents_base64` variable to a file.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to `fs::write`, there's a generalized solution for everything implementing the [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) trait, by using [`write_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all):

```rust
use std::io::Write; // bring trait into scope
use std::fs;

// ... later in code
let mut file = fs::OpenOptions::new()
    // .create(true) // To create a new file
    .write(true)
    // either use the ? operator or unwrap since it returns a Result
    .open("/path/to/file")?;

file.write_all(&file_contents_base64);
```

Comment: Please look for duplicates and vote to close questions before answering.

Comment: What is OpenOptions?

Answer (score 8):

The fact that you're using the [`image-base64` crate](https://crates.io/crates/image-base64) seems less relevant to the question. Considering you just want to write a `Vec<u8>` to a file, then you can just use e.g. [`fs::write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.write.html):

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;

let file_contents_base64: Vec<u8> = ...;
let path: &Path = ...;

fs::write(path, file_contents_base64).unwrap();
```

Comment: Please look for duplicates and vote to close questions before answering.